# Trying to write a newcommand to wrap text in bold parentheses

Tags: math-mode, macros, bold, preamble, boldsymbol

I am attempting to define a command `\ideal` that will wrap its argument in bold parentheses.
Here is my attempt: `\newcommand{\ideal}[1]{\boldsymbol{\left(\right.} #1 \boldsymbol{\left.\right)}}`

This compiles correctly visually (on overleaf) but produces this error:

> You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’. Use $...$ for inline math mode, and [...] or one of the mathematical environments (e.g. equation) for display math mode. This applies to symbols such as subscripts ( _ ), integrals ( \int ), Greek letters ( \alpha, \beta, \delta ) and modifiers (\vec{x}, \tilde{x} ).

If I use too many of them in the same document, it will not compile at all.

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example showing how you want to use your macro? If you really want to wrap text in it (not parts of equations) then using `\boldsymbol` is the wrong approach (as well as using `\left` and `\right`), instead you could use something like this: `\newcommand\ideal[1]{\textbf{(}#1\textbf{)}}`. As it is currently defined the `\left` and `\right` calls don't do anything useful anyway

Comment: I was using ```\left``` and ```\right``` so that the parentheses would resize.

Comment: But they don't if the material you want them to enclose isn't between the `\left` and `\right`. What you're doing is using two empty pairs of `\left` and `\right`. This way it won't resize to anything.

Comment: I did not realize this... Thank you!

Comment: note that you have not provided any example that would produce an error an dthe text that youquote is not a tex error message, it may be some help text from an editor. So it is rather hard to guess what you have actually done wrong (although as Skillmon says your definition is a bit strange but should not generate errors)

Comment: I also don't see why it should generate errors. I am not sure what you mean by an example as it doesn't compile at all (I am using overleaf if that is relevant).

Comment: an example should start `\documentclass`, and end `\end{document}` and be a example of the error that you are asking about. Otherwise we can only guess what code you have that is generating the error, here I'd guess that you have used `\ideal` outside of math mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `bm` package

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand\ideal[1]{\bm(#1\bm)}

\begin{document}

$(x) +\ideal{x}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks the way I want, but now my command ```\newcommand{\NN}[1]{\mathscr{N}\left(#1\right)}``` is ignored and it prints a nonscript N.

Comment: @KaceyReidy that is completely unrelated though. `\mathscr` is not a  standard command you must have loaded some package to define it perhaps the `euscript` package, but there are several script font package. Nothing here is related to script fonts.

Comment: I have realized the error with changing the ideal command: it makes it so that I load too many math alphabets. So, I need to fix the ideal command without using ```bm```

Comment: @KaceyReidy you could use `\boldsymbol` instead (but `\bm` gives the correct spacing) the bm package shouldn't make you run out of alphabets, did you load it last as it documents?